# Click of Button Opens Web Browser?

Tags: c#

how can i make it so when i click a button it will open a web browser and open the html file within the project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) . It can be used to launch the browser .

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305703) has a nice example on how to do this.

**EDIT** You can then use a file URI to open a local file, for example:

file:///C:/Foo/Bar/Baz/myHtml.htm

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar and I didn't want to call a specific browser, but rather the default browser of the user.  After messing around for a while I decided to just experiment with the following...and it worked flawlessly:

```
 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
    }
```